# Testing action in state that selects from another state sometimes fails with "Class constructor FileState cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, ngxs

So I have a NGXS state class which has an Action and handler that looks like this:

```
export interface TaggingStateModel {
  tagging: string;
}

export class UpdateTagging {
  static type = '[Tagging] UpdateTagging';
}

@State<TaggingStateModel>({
  name: 'tagging',
  defaults: {tagging: null}
})
export class TaggingState {
  constructor(public store: Store) {}

  @Action(UpdateTagging)
  onUpdateTagging(ctx: StateContext<TaggingStateModel>) {
    const activeFile: string = this.store.selectSnapshot(FileState.getActiveFile);

    ctx.setState({tagging: activeFile});
  }
}
```

My components can thus dispatch the `UpdateTagging` action, and that will get a snapshot using one of the selectors from FileState, which looks like this:

```
export interface FileStateModel {
  activeFile: string;
}

@State<FileStateModel>({
  name: 'file',
  defaults: {activeFile: null}
})
export class FileState {
  @Selector()
  static getActiveFile(state: FileStateModel): string {
    return state.activeFile;
  }
}
```

Now, I go to write unit tests for `TaggingState`, and start with something simple like this:

```
describe('TagAssignmentState', () => {

  let store: Store;
  const activeFile = 'activeFile';

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([TaggingState, FileState])]
    });
    store = TestBed.get(Store);

    store.reset({
      tagging:{
          tagging: undefined
      },
      file:{
          activeFile: fileGuid
      }
    });
  });

  it('UpdateTagging testing', async () => {
    await store.dispatch(new UpdateTagging()).toPromise();

    const taggingStateModel: TaggingStateModel = store.selectSnapshot(TaggingState);
    expect(taggingStateModel.tagging).toEqual(activeFile);
  });
})
```

So this appears to work... sometimes. But occasionally the test will fail, with an error `Class constructor FileState cannot be invoked without 'new'`. Maybe 1/6 attempts will fail. I can't get the error to occur more or less often, no matter what I do.

Looking around online for other people having this error, they all indicate it may have something to do with my compiler module, which I currently have set to `esnext` and would prefer to keep it that way. One thing suggested turning it back to es5, but angular doesn't even seem to support that any more.

I've tried commenting out other tests in the same class to see if that affects thing, but it does not. I've tried using `return await this.store.select(FileState.getActiveFile).toPromise()` but it just occasionally returns `undefined` instead of the string. If I add a `.pipe(filter(activeFile => !!activeFile))` it will just never emit anything and fail.

If you need more context on this I can try to provide, but at this point I'm honestly not even sure what's relevant. The closest thing I could find was [this discussion](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/773), but I'm not even sure that it's related to the same thing, as I'm not doing anything related to the `APP_INITIALIZER`.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you create an issue with provided reproduction on NGXS GitHub repo? I will pick it up and will try to fix (if some defect really exists)

Comment: Unfortunately, try as I might, I can't reproduce it in a minimal repo :( As I mentioned, I really can't even begin to imagine what might be causing this. My most minimal attempt is not having issues, and I just don't know what i should even add to start causing issues. It could be other tests I have interfering with the running tests, it could be the module, it could be lazy or differential loading... I genuinely don't have a clue :( And of course the actual code base this example is abstracted from is both large and proprietary, so that's a non-starter as well.

Comment: @overthesanity in terms of a best solution, a major start would just be the ability to provide a mocked out global state rather than having to import a real NgxsModule in every test. It just completely breaks the concept of unit testing when errors in state could cause unit testing errors for components (or even other state classes, like in this example).

Comment: ok, could you post your question on slack general channel?

Comment: It's alright, as long as there are workarounds, I understand the team is busy and these things don't happen overnight. Slack general channel?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the NGXS guide for unit testing: https://www.ngxs.io/recipes/unit-testing

Following that guide, for this scenario I will do this test:

```
describe('TagAssignmentState', () => {

  let store: Store;
  const activeFile = 'activeFile';

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([TaggingState, FileState])]
    });
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    store.reset({
      tagging:{
          tagging: undefined
      },
      file:{
          activeFile: fileGuid
      }
    });
  }));

  it('UpdateTagging testing', () => {
  spyOn(store,'selectSnapshot').and.returnValue(activeFile);
  store.dispatch(new UpdateTagging());
  store.selectOnce(state => state.tagging).subscribe(
    (tag) => {
       expect(tag).toEqual(activeFile);
    }
  );
})
```

Now I think that should work.

Comment: I have been following that guide, but you're right, I forgot I was using selectSnapshot in my test instead of Select. Either way, the error occurs before it even gets to that part of the code - it's thrown in the UpdateTagging method, when selectSnapshot is called the first time, because the FileState is not defined yet. Making this change does not make a difference.

Comment: Also, your test is testing file state, but my goal is to test TaggingState.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the problem. Ok, in that case, we can mock the FileState. I have just updated my answer, check now if it works.

Comment: Hmmm.. this should work, though it's not ideal. It means that I can't use `this.store.selectSnapshot()` anywhere else in the process lest it get mocked in the same way, and I've still yet to find a way to mock store methods based on arguments. However, it is a good point, I might be able to refactor to do something like this. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @GermanQuinteros what you've provided is not actually valid and this error is not related to this. You should never perform expectations inside the subscribe block as the observer can be asynchronous and the test will complete before it emits some value. What is provided in the NGXS guide is not valid also, I updated the unit testing guide prolly 2-3 months ago and it doesn't get updated (on the website)... :(

Comment: Hi @overthesanity, I understand what you say. Should I set the test async() ? ``` it('UpdateTagging testing', async(() => {...})) ``` because in that case if the subscription won't executes the test will fail. Is it correct?
On the other hand, where I can find the unit testing guide updated? Thanks.

Comment: You can solve the async issue rather easily by using `done`, to force the method to wait until the observer has emitted and the expects have been run before terminating.

Edit: Looking at the documentation https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/docs/recipes/unit-testing.md again, I see they actually use the selectSnapshot approach. Unfortunately, if I'm mocking out selectSnapshot, I can't use that in my testing either.

Comment: @EaterOfFromage see my comment right under your question